# Magento2 - setData() For Added Fields

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have added a field(key) in table(quote_item) through module installation(InstallSchema) and in Api Code I am using the following code to add value for that. But its not adding the value to that field in DB.

```
//cartItemObject \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item
$cartItemObject->setData("key", "value");
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Before making the setData, did you start the model? If you are using factory you should do as follows:

```
$cartItemObject=$this->model->create(); // after this you would have access to the following methods getData(), setData(), etc
```

In any case if it still does not work I advise you to review [this information](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html) for handling model in magento 2